# Web service Question

Tags: c#

I build Web service, I define IP connection (all works excellent)

but, how I can define the IP in variable ?

now, I change with the Find and replace in VS2008 and right click on the

Web service properties.

thank's in advance

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that I understand your question, but I think you are asking how you get your client application to call the web service on a specific IP address? If that is the case, there should be a section in you App.config (or web.config if it is a web client) where the address to the web service is specified.

Another alternative is to do it programatically (let's say that the web service is called "MyService"):

```
MyService serviceInstance = new MyService();
serviceInstance.Url = @"http://myserver/myservice.asmx";
// execute web service method of choice here...
```

Comment: I want to wright the IP in my program and that I can change it